# Payment Intent is not defined:TypeScript

Tags: stripe-payments

i am following stripe official docs to integrated subscription module. But i am getting error while writing same code:

Payment Intent is not defined:TypeScript

Error: Property 'payment_intent' does not exist on type 'string | Invoice'.
Property 'payment_intent' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)

```
exports.doSubscribe = functions.https.onRequest(async (data, res) => {
  try {
    ///Create Customer
    const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
      description: 'My First Test Customer (created for API docs at https://www.stripe.com/docs/api)',
    });
   

    ///Create Payment Method
    const paymentMethod = await stripe.paymentMethods.create({
      type: 'card',
      card: {
        number: '4242424242424242',
        exp_month: 10,
        exp_year: 2023,
        cvc: '314',
      },
    });


    ///Attach Payment Method with Customer
    await stripe.paymentMethods.attach(
      paymentMethod.id,
        {customer:customer.id}
      );

    ///Crate Product
    const product = await stripe.products.create({
      name: 'Gold Special',
    });
    

    ///Create Price
    const price = await stripe.prices.create({
      unit_amount: 1000,
      currency: 'usd',
      recurring: {interval: 'month'},
      product: product.id,
    });

    ///Create Subscription
    const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
      customer: customer.id,
      items: [
        {price: price.id},
      ],
      payment_behavior: 'default_incomplete',
      payment_settings: { save_default_payment_method: 'on_subscription' },
      expand: ['latest_invoice.payment_intent'],
    });
  
    res.send({
      subscriptionId: subscription.id,

      clientSecret: subscription!.latest_invoice!.payment_intent.client_secret,
      
      Property 'payment_intent' does not exist on type 'string | Invoice'.
      Property 'payment_intent' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)
    });
   
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`error: ${error}`);
    // return null;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like TypeScript is unable to determine `subscription.latest_invoice` as an Invoice object.

I'd recommend to cast `subscription.latest_invoice` to Invoice object and `subscription.latest_invoice.payment_intent` to PaymentIntent object manually. For example,

```
const invoice = subscription.latest_invoice as Stripe.Invoice;
if (invoice.payment_intent) {
  const intent = invoice.payment_intent as Stripe.PaymentIntent;
  res.send({
    subscriptionId: subscription.id,
    clientSecret: intent.client_secret,
  });
}
```